# Module not found: Can't resolve './NewsCard/NewsCard' in Voice Assistant App

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I'm facing this error react saying can't resolve. maybe some problems with the path. pls, help me with the issue.

Comment: isn't that `NewsCard` ? to go up the directory use `..` as  `../NewsCard/NewsCard`

Answer (score 0):

Please try updating the import statement as : (Line 4 of NewsCards)

```
import NewsCard from '../NewsCard/NewsCard'
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 4, try changing to `import NewsCard from "../NewsCard/NewsCard"`